# System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException For Kinect

Tags: c#, exception, kinect, gesture, kinect-sdk

Im currently facing a weird problem with the Microsoft Kinect SDK 2.0 Browser Sample code of Discrete Gesture Basics-WPF

Objective: is to add my own recording of the gesture in filename.gbd into the database and able to extract the gesture inside.

Problem: When i changed the initial name from 'Seated.gbd' to 'RightHandHandsUp.gbd' The error occured below.

However, if i were to rename my 'RightHandHandsUp.gbd' file to 'Seated.gbd' ( the default), it would work. Which is weird, but i suspect there is some binding somewhere in the program but i have already tried searching the entire project for the keyword.

Thanks in advance!!

> Error Message:
>   [image: Error Message1]

```
System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: ''The invocation of the constructor on type 'Microsoft.Samples.Kinect.DiscreteGestureBasics.MainWindow' that matches the specified binding constraints threw an exception.' Line number '4' and line position '9'.'
```

With 2 inner exceptions:

```
InvalidOperationException: This API has returned an exception from an HRESULT: 0x80004005
```

And

```
COMException: Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.
```

> so in the GestureDetector.cs file where i changed the name of the file.

```
 //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <copyright file="GestureDetector.cs" company="Microsoft">
//     Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
// </copyright>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace Microsoft.Samples.Kinect.DiscreteGestureBasics
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using Microsoft.Kinect;
    using Microsoft.Kinect.VisualGestureBuilder;

/// <summary>
/// Gesture Detector class which listens for VisualGestureBuilderFrame events from the service
/// and updates the associated GestureResultView object with the latest results for the 'Seated' gesture
/// </summary>
public class GestureDetector : IDisposable
{
    /// <summary> Path to the gesture database that was trained with VGB </summary>
    private readonly string gestureDatabase = @"Database\RightHandHandsUp.gbd";

    /// <summary> Name of the discrete gesture in the database that we want to track </summary>
    private readonly string seatedGestureName = "HandsUp_Right";

    /// <summary> Gesture frame source which should be tied to a body tracking ID </summary>
    private VisualGestureBuilderFrameSource vgbFrameSource = null;

    /// <summary> Gesture frame reader which will handle gesture events coming from the sensor </summary>
    private VisualGestureBuilderFrameReader vgbFrameReader = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the GestureDetector class along with the gesture frame source and reader
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="kinectSensor">Active sensor to initialize the VisualGestureBuilderFrameSource object with</param>
    /// <param name="gestureResultView">GestureResultView object to store gesture results of a single body to</param>
    public GestureDetector(KinectSensor kinectSensor, GestureResultView gestureResultView)
    {
        if (kinectSensor == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("kinectSensor");
        }

        if (gestureResultView == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("gestureResultView");
        }

        this.GestureResultView = gestureResultView;

        // create the vgb source. The associated body tracking ID will be set when a valid body frame arrives from the sensor.
        this.vgbFrameSource = new VisualGestureBuilderFrameSource(kinectSensor, 0);
        this.vgbFrameSource.TrackingIdLost += this.Source_TrackingIdLost;

        // open the reader for the vgb frames
        this.vgbFrameReader = this.vgbFrameSource.OpenReader();
        if (this.vgbFrameReader != null)
        {
            this.vgbFrameReader.IsPaused = true;
            this.vgbFrameReader.FrameArrived += this.Reader_GestureFrameArrived;
        }

        // load the 'Seated' gesture from the gesture database
        using (VisualGestureBuilderDatabase database = new VisualGestureBuilderDatabase(this.gestureDatabase))
        {
            // we could load all available gestures in the database with a call to vgbFrameSource.AddGestures(database.AvailableGestures), 
            // but for this program, we only want to track one discrete gesture from the database, so we'll load it by name
            foreach (Gesture gesture in database.AvailableGestures)
            {
                if (gesture.Name.Equals(this.seatedGestureName))
                {
                    this.vgbFrameSource.AddGesture(gesture);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary> Gets the GestureResultView object which stores the detector results for display in the UI </summary>
    public GestureResultView GestureResultView { get; private set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the body tracking ID associated with the current detector
    /// The tracking ID can change whenever a body comes in/out of scope
    /// </summary>
    public ulong TrackingId
    {
        get
        {
            return this.vgbFrameSource.TrackingId;
        }

        set
        {
            if (this.vgbFrameSource.TrackingId != value)
            {
                this.vgbFrameSource.TrackingId = value;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets a value indicating whether or not the detector is currently paused
    /// If the body tracking ID associated with the detector is not valid, then the detector should be paused
    /// </summary>
    public bool IsPaused
    {
        get
        {
            return this.vgbFrameReader.IsPaused;
        }

        set
        {
            if (this.vgbFrameReader.IsPaused != value)
            {
                this.vgbFrameReader.IsPaused = value;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Disposes all unmanaged resources for the class
    /// </summary>
    public void Dispose()
    {
        this.Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Disposes the VisualGestureBuilderFrameSource and VisualGestureBuilderFrameReader objects
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="disposing">True if Dispose was called directly, false if the GC handles the disposing</param>
    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            if (this.vgbFrameReader != null)
            {
                this.vgbFrameReader.FrameArrived -= this.Reader_GestureFrameArrived;
                this.vgbFrameReader.Dispose();
                this.vgbFrameReader = null;
            }

            if (this.vgbFrameSource != null)
            {
                this.vgbFrameSource.TrackingIdLost -= this.Source_TrackingIdLost;
                this.vgbFrameSource.Dispose();
                this.vgbFrameSource = null;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Handles gesture detection results arriving from the sensor for the associated body tracking Id
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">object sending the event</param>
    /// <param name="e">event arguments</param>
    private void Reader_GestureFrameArrived(object sender, VisualGestureBuilderFrameArrivedEventArgs e)
    {
        VisualGestureBuilderFrameReference frameReference = e.FrameReference;
        using (VisualGestureBuilderFrame frame = frameReference.AcquireFrame())
        {
            if (frame != null)
            {
                // get the discrete gesture results which arrived with the latest frame
                IReadOnlyDictionary<Gesture, DiscreteGestureResult> discreteResults = frame.DiscreteGestureResults;

                if (discreteResults != null)
                {
                    // we only have one gesture in this source object, but you can get multiple gestures
                    foreach (Gesture gesture in this.vgbFrameSource.Gestures)
                    {
                        if (gesture.Name.Equals(this.seatedGestureName) && gesture.GestureType == GestureType.Discrete)
                        {
                            DiscreteGestureResult result = null;
                            discreteResults.TryGetValue(gesture, out result);

                            if (result != null)
                            {
                                // update the GestureResultView object with new gesture result values
                                this.GestureResultView.UpdateGestureResult(true, result.Detected, result.Confidence);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Handles the TrackingIdLost event for the VisualGestureBuilderSource object
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">object sending the event</param>
    /// <param name="e">event arguments</param>
    private void Source_TrackingIdLost(object sender, TrackingIdLostEventArgs e)
    {
        // update the GestureResultView object to show the 'Not Tracked' image in the UI
        this.GestureResultView.UpdateGestureResult(false, false, 0.0f);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I am now facing the same issue! Did you solve the problem? :)

Comment: @user3913217 it has been quite a while so I’ll try to remember what i think i did to solve it. You would have to remove seated.gdb file from the database. In addition you are able to add more than one file.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I didn't know that DiscreteGestureBasics is using AdaBoostTech.dll and RFRProgressTech.dll. I copied directory vgtech from DiscreteGestureBuilder example bin directory to my other project bin directory and everything works fine.